# Using the API to search for users filtering by something other than startswith

Tags: core-api

I'm building a search input that would use the API to look for users and use that information for something else.

Right now I'm using this:

```
/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id,Title&$filter=startswith(Title,'lastname')
```

And it gives me the user I'm looking for, however some users might not search using the last name of the person (Title being in the form of: Last Name, First Name). I was wondering if there's a way to make substringof work as a filter in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
$filter=substringof('lastOrFirstName', Title)
```

Possibly you should switch places of the parameters to `substringof`, not certain of the ordering there.

Great intro:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx